# How to programmatically append text to a QML TextArea?

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to pass log data to my QML front end, one line at a time, and have it append to the end of a TextArea. I've considered several approaches. The following is the most promising. I have created a QAbstractListModel (in Python) and pass this model into a repeater where it arrives as a single item (rowCount =1) which I append to the TextArea using the line

```
text: terminal_text.text + display
```

This works but I get this warning everytime the text is updated.

```
file://.../TextArea.qml:728:9: QML QQuickTextEdit*: Binding loop detected for property "text"
```

See below for the code of the repeater.

```
Repeater {
    model: TerminalFeed { }
    delegate: TextArea {
        id: terminal_text
        font.family: "Courier"
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        readOnly: true
        selectByMouse: true
        wrapMode: TextEdit.NoWrap
        horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded
        verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded
        text: terminal_text.text + display
    }
}
```

How can I stop this happening? Alternatively does anyone have a better way of achieving the same result?

Comment: Referring to the Qt documentation it may not be the best way to use a Repeater here, quoting the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-repeater.html) of the Repeater: "This (Repeater) can be inefficient if there are a large number of delegate items and not all of the items are required to be visible at the same time".
Instead a more efficient solution could be the [ListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to show logged data in a QML window.

I use the `insert()` method, which is inherited from [QML TextField](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#insert-method). The insertion position is the length of the `TextArea`.

```
TextArea {
    id: outputTextArea
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    data = "dummyString"
    outputTextArea.insert(outputTextArea.length, data)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, that is indeed a binding loop because `text` is dependent on its own value. If QML didn't detect it and break it, an infinite loop of updating would result.

Instead of using a binding, you can do something like this:

```
Repeater {
    model: TerminalFeed { }
    delegate: TextArea {
        id: terminal_text
        font.family: "Courier"
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        readOnly: true
        selectByMouse: true
        wrapMode: TextEdit.NoWrap
        horizontalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded
        verticalScrollBarPolicy: Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded

        onDisplayChanged: {
            text = text + display;
        }
    }

}
```

With the original binding approach, it will try and update whenever either `display` *or* `text` changes. With this approach, it will only try and update whenever `display` changes – which is what you really want.

Comment: I'm getting 'Cannot assign to non-existent property "onDisplayChanged"' - Do I need to be importing a particular QtQuick package or version?

Comment: Move `onDisplayChanged` to wherever the `display` property is declared.
Btw I don't think you need a model and repeater if you always have a single item in your model. Just use a simple `TextArea` with a `display` string property updated from Python and use the code above for the TextArea.

Comment: Hhhmm, I thought the roles would have changed signals for them. Could be only the model does - try `onModelChanged` instead.